# Триггер для вставки значения в зависимости от номера строки

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Имеется таблица, в которой в клиенте будет заполняться одно поле, остальные поля будут подтягиваться и создаваться посредством триггеров.
Одно из таких создаваемых полей должно заполняться след. образом

```
"постоянная часть (3.2.БИМ)" || "номер вставленной сроки, дополненный слева нулями до 4 символов" || "год вставки".
```

Т.е. первая строка, добавленная в таблицу в этом году, должна содержать в данном поле

```
3.2.БИМ.0001.2017
```

Вторая, соответственно,

```
3.2.БИМ.0002.2017
```

и т.д.
Решил добавлять данные значения триггером, однако не знаю, как в триггере объявить элемент с rownum. Точнее, знаю, что хочу положить это значение в переменную и использовать lpad, однако, честно говоря, к чему именно его использовать в моем случае - не знаю.
Сам недоделанный триггер:

```
create or replace trigger TIUB_j_standart_reg
  before insert or update on j_standart_reg  
  for each row
declare
  l_Year varchar2;
begin
  l_Year := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
  if :new.equ_id is not null then




      :new.standart_num := '3.2.БИМ.'|| ______________ || l_Year;
  end if;
end TIUB_j_standart_reg;
```

Большим разрывом и нижним подчеркиванием показал места, которые не знаю, как заполнить. Буду благодарен за подсказку в решении, хотя бы как правильно объявить rownum в триггере.

Comment: Допустимы ли разрывы в нумерации? Что делать, если записей будет больше 10000 за год?

Comment: @Dmitry, записей за год не будет более 200, однако стандарт предполагает наличие в данной части 4 символов. Могу уточнить что за разрывы нумерации? Если, например, запись была удалена?

Comment: Разрывы - это значит, что у вас будут записи `3.2.БИМ.0001.2017` и `3.2.БИМ.0003.2017`, а записи `3.2.БИМ.0002.2017` может не оказаться и ничего с этим поделать будет нельзя.

Comment: Уточните версию Oracle

Comment: @defaultlocale, Oracle 9.
Dmitry, записи удаляться не будут, соответственно и разрыва нумерации не предвидится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить использовать последовательности (SEQUENCE). Сначала ее нужно создать один раз:

```
create sequence my_seq nocache;
```

Потом можно использовать:

```
create or replace trigger TIUB_j_standart_reg
  before insert or update on j_standart_reg  
  for each row
declare
  l_Year varchar2;
begin
  l_Year := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
  if :new.equ_id is not null then
      :new.standart_num := '3.2.БИМ.'|| to_char(my_seq.nextval, '0000') || l_Year;
  end if;
end TIUB_j_standart_reg;
```

Проблем две:

1. В случае отката транзакции значение сиквенса назад не откатывается. Если вы вызвали `nextval` и текущее значение стало 2, потом возникла ошибка в другом месте и транзакция откатилась, в следующий раз у вас вставится 3.
2. Сбрасывать значение на 1 раз в год придется вручную, ну или создать джоб, который будет пересоздавать сиквенс каждое первое января рано утром.

Comment: @Dmitry , вопрос. С первым моментом понятно, со вторым - не совсем - для чего каждый год необходимо пересоздавать последовательность?

Comment: @n0n4m3 Вы же говорите, что вам надо начинать нумерацию каждый год сначала? Вот чтобы сбросить счетчик и приходится его пересоздавать.

Comment: @Dmitry, вы наверное меня неправильно поняли, или я неправильно выразился - я сказал лишь что за год не будет добавлено более 200 записей. Нумерация должна быть сквозная, т.е. продолжаться из года в год. Спасибо за решение, сейчас попробую его использовать.

Comment: @n0n4m3 А, ну так даже проще. Проблема номер 2 отпадает сама собой. Только nocache добавьте, как выше советовали (я ответ отредактировал).

Comment: @Dmitry, developer ругается что таблица или последовательность недопустима в данном контексте, даже если значение кладу в переменную. Не подскажете, как можно обойти?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю, с 9-м ораклом не работал почти. Попробуйте присваивать значение переменной с помощью `select my_seq.nextval into ny_variable from dual;`. Полагаю, что с правами у вас все в порядке.

Comment: Заработало после небольшой доработки. Большое спасибо!